# How do I prove that $\{3k+2 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{3k-1 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I have to prove that

$$\{3k+2 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{3k-1 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

I don't want anyone to prove it for me but to suggest a way to start it. I have no idea at this point which method of proof should i use?

Comment: Show set inclusion. That is $\{3k+2:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq\{3k-1:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{3k-1:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq\{3k+2:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** k ranges over the integers. What happens if you take k = h-1 on the first set?

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot and i am pretty sure i now have the correct proof. Thanks :)    Also thanks to others because they were also very helpful answers

Comment: @user2166592 You're very welcome :). Remember you can accept my answer by clicking the tick sign just below the vote count. This scores points for both of us!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Solve $\ 3k+2 = 3j-1 \ $ firstly for $j,\,$ secondly for $\,k.$

Answer (score 1):

A good general way to prove that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal is to show that:

1. If $a \in A$ then $a \in B$, and
2. If $b \in B$ then $b \in A$.

In your case, this is fairly straightforward: if $a \in A$, then $a = 3k+2$ for some $k$, so $a = 3(k+1)-1$, so $a \in B$.  Hopefully you can work out the proof in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try do define a bijection between the two sets. that's not an hard task to perform. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:
$$\{3k+2:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{3k+3-1:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{3(k+1)-1:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
but if $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $k+1\in \mathbb{Z}$ too.
Thus
$$\{3k+2:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{3k-1:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$